# How to add navigation drawer on pre built app?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I am new to android development.  I have already built my app without navigation drawer. Now, I want to add navigation drawer which will be same across all activities in my app. Help me on this issue.

Comment: Easiest way would have been using only one Activity with a NavigationDrawer and using Fragments for different content (instead of the old way of having many different Activities)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your original activities are extending 'AppCompatActivity', make base activity like following and extend your all other activities to 'BaseActivity'. BaseActivity layout will content DrawaerLayout and one framelayout.  Inside BaseActivity ovveride setcontentview method and inflat your activity layout inside framelayout.

BaseActivity.Java

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    private FrameLayout baseLayout;
    public ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    public Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.base_layout);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById( R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        baseLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.base_view);
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, 0, 0);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view) {
        if (baseLayout != null) {
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            baseLayout.addView(view, params);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        if (baseLayout != null) {
            baseLayout.addView(view, params);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        //TODO
        return false;
    }
}
```

base_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MyApp.Toolbar.Solid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">


            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>



        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/base_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="280sp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/base_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

base_header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/blank"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/nav_header_icon"
        android:layout_width="50sp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16sp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/nav_header_title"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nav_header_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/nav_header_subtitle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nav_header_subtitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Add drawer.xml in "menu" folder in your resources.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_home"
        android:title="Home" />


</menu>
```

Comment: <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_bar_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/base_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer" />

Comment: in above code pl explain menu and headerLayout part

Comment: Oh, I used my default values. You can replace it with your values. Make Header and Drawer layout and add them,

Comment: but what to add in headerLayout and menu

Comment: pl also upload your @layout/base_header and @menu/drawer file

Comment: @MerajAhmed , just added those layouts. Check answer now. You can replace icon and dimensions according to your requirement

Comment: what to inflate in setContentView and how to add to frame layout

Comment: BaseActivity has override the setcontentview() method . Check the code. Now only think you have to do is extend your activities to "BaseActivity" instead "AppCompatActivity".